# Fragments reuse

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is it somehow possible to reuse [fragments](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/1.0.0/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1)?

In an example like this

```
def unpublished_by_title(title) do
  from p in Post,
    where: is_nil(p.published_at) and
           fragment("downcase(?)", p.title) == ^title
end
```

It seems like it would be very convenient to be able to extract fragment-part into a separate function so that it can be reused in other places, e.g.:

```
def unpublished_by_title(title) do
  from p in Post,
    where: is_nil(p.published_at) and
           downcase(p.title) == ^title
end

def downcase(title) do
  fragment("downcase(?)", ^title)
end
```

however, after trying many different variations it seems like this wouldn't work because of macro expansions or something like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, queries are composed at compile time. Because of this, if you want to extend query syntax, you need to define macros instead of regular functions.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
defmacro downcase(field) do
  quote do
    fragment("downcase(?)", unquote(field))
  end
end
```

Remember you need to define macro before you use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Sadly I tried this and it didn't work out, I wrote about a possible reason in the update part of the question.

Comment: @ave works perfectly for me. Did you make sure the macro is defined _above_ the function that uses it?